# Change default timezone to America Pacific

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, python, timezone

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;
Result: SYSTEM  SYSTEM

 SELECT CURRENT_TIME;
 Result: 06:25:07
```

> But MY System time is 11.55 AM IST  and PST TIME is 11.25 PM
>
> How can I change timezone to AMERICA PACIFIC as 11.25 PM in both
>   MYSQL Workbench and using python.

Comment: *But MY System time is 11.55 AM IST* You now tell about OS where MySQL is running on?

Comment: My local Windows O.S is IST AND vdi timezone is also IST. and I am using mysql workbench in VDI

Comment: MYSQL is running on RDS instance of AWS

Comment: Any suggestion on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used below query to convert `UTC timezone` to `America Pacific`. Field
> value would be in **`timestamp(6)`**.

```
CONVERT_TZ(field,'UTC','US/Pacific')
```